# Using sequelize-cli in Node 14 with type: module

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, es6-modules, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to set up the project using `Node v14.3` and `sequelize`.

I don't want to use `babel-register`. Instead of this I set `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` and use all ES6 - ES11 features out of the box.

I also want to use `sequelize-cli` for setting up and applying migrations. Everything works except the following command:

```
& sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.3.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.11]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
== 20200530214311-create-user: migrating =======

ERROR: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/kasheftin/work/tests/chai-http-publication/migrations/20200530214311-create-user.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/kasheftin/work/tests/chai-http-publication/migrations/20200530214311-create-user.js from /home/kasheftin/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3.0/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/node_modules/umzug/lib/migration.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename 20200530214311-create-user.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/kasheftin/work/tests/chai-http-publication/package.json.
```

We see that under the hood `sequelize-cli` uses `require()`. That's not allowed for ES Module. It suggests 3 ways to solve this:

- rename 20200530214311-create-user.js to end in .cjs - Can not be done, sequelize-cli does not find migrations that end with .cjs.
- Change the requiring code to use import() - I don't want to touch sequelize-cli code.
- Remove "type": "module" - I can not because everything stops working.

Is there any other way to make `sequelize-cli` work? I'm using tests heavily and I want the test database to be prepared automatically before running tests.

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/861 is still open. Maybe you can use a workaround only?

Comment: Thanks, @Anatoly. Installing the **babel-core** package and adding require("babel-core/register"); to my config.cjs file did the trick for me, just like mentioned in the link. Besides that, I also needed to install **babel-preset-env** in order to get it working.

Comment: You're not a author of the original question. Can I copy my comment as an answer?

Comment: Yes. So the answer is it's not possible at the moment.

Comment: So I can't use sequelize-cli with Nodejs v14's ES6? Ok, now my whole project is officially screwed up

Comment: Anatoly @Anatoly that link isn’t working anymore? But the issue doesn’t appear to be resolved or has something changed. I have identical issue. Can someone confirm that if I use Babel as the work around that when I go live everything will work? I guess alternative is to refactor my backend code to es5 standard, which would be a shame I’d like to benefit from node 14 ability. Thanks

Comment: There is `babel-register` mentioned in the official documentation: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html. It seems this is the official way to use es6

Comment: thanks for replying, i'll look in to

Answer (score 7):

A solution is to add a `package.json` in your migrations folder to override the `type: "module"` from your main package.json

This package.json would look like this:

```
{
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

and your migration file have to look like this:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {

  }
};
```

It works well with nodeJS `14.16.1` & Sequelize `6.6.2` & sequelize-cli `6.2.0`

Comment: This works for me with NodeJS 18 and Sequelize 6.19.0

Comment: it works, but break other app functionalities

Comment: @mohammadJavadGhasemy if you create the package.json in a specific folder it's not supposed to break anything

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue for months now. Babel register would just not work while using ES module imports and Sequelize cli.

Here's how I eventually got everything to work properly.
I had to copy **src** to a **dist** directory. Then override the **type** in package json. Hopefully this helps out

.sequelizerc

```js
require('@babel/register')({
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]
  ]
});
const path = require('path');

const DB_PATH = 'dist/db'; // use dist instead of src directory

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve(DB_PATH, 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve(DB_PATH, 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve(DB_PATH, 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve(DB_PATH, 'migrations')
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.18",
    "yarn": ">=1.22"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node src",
    "db": "sequelize db:migrate && sequelize db:seed:all",
    "predb": "yarn dist",
    "dist": "cp -r src dist",
    "predist": "rm -rf dist",
    "postdist": "node setup-dist.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.16.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.8.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

setup-dist.js

```js
import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';

const file = './dist/package.json';
const data = '{ "type": "" }'; // to override ESM in main package.json

writeFileSync(file, data);
```

Reference: https://gist.github.com/elawad/c0af86ea37629ad0538c2b974b4ea0c1

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by creating a `.sequelizerc` file to let sequelize know that I am overriding the default paths:

```
// .sequelizerc
const path = require('path');

const db_path = './';

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve(db_path, 'config/config.cjs'),
  'models-path': path.resolve(db_path, 'models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve(db_path, 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve(db_path, 'migrations')
};
```

Notice that I am using a `config.cjs` file. Then just create a migration but change the extension to .cjs as well:

```
// 20211206164144-create_subjects_table.cjs
const tableName = 'subjects';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable(tableName, {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        required: true,
      },
      created_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updated_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      deleted_at: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('subjects');
  },
};
```

This is working with Node.js version v16.13.1 and the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.0-beta.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: your sequelizerc file is using commonjs, now change that to esm and see the errors it pops