# Sequelize ORM, is this normal that we have to put database info into a json file?

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am trying to go deeper with Sequelize and especially using migration. But, I can't imagine that the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) requires that we use a json file to put database info. So, my question is, "how can this be possible when I am using Git and GiHub for my project?" If I decide to ignore the file, how can my colleagues get to know about the exact structure I am using? Or am I missing something? Should you share your exact workflow for Sequelize, Postgress and Git?

Comment: If you meant credentials and IP and server/DB names then you can easily use JS-config and get them there from anywhere you want (typically environment variables that are set outside).

Comment: It's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal to put your database info in either a json or js file, for better and improved security you should pull your database configurations from a .env file or from ENV Variables on your server. i.e instead of:

```
development: {
    username: 'database_dev',
    password: 'database_dev',
    database: 'database_dev',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
```

You should have something like this in your config file:

```
development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    dialect: process.env.DIALECT
}
```

Notice that your username and password now come from **process.env**.

You will then have to create a .env file that will contain all sensitive information like passwords and this file **you will have to add to .gitignore and never commit it to git**. Read more about env files [here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786).

When sharing your code to github, you include your config.json/config.js file but your colleagues or potential hackers won't know the username, password or any database configurations and this is done on purpose to avoid having sensitive information like passwords in your code.

The database configuration will then have to be shared with them separately or can only exist on one of your servers as ENV Variables.

Comment: Thank you, @Leon. I did use this solution before, but still didn't work. Now I go the solution I was looking for. Let me share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find what I was looking for, so I don't know any other way to share it if not with this answer box.

I got inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304477/sequelize-run-migration-with-es6-and-modules)

1. install `babel-register` as dev dependency
2. `require` it in `.sequelizerc`
3. make sure the config file is in a `cjs` format. It's a commonJS file ext.